# How to run cpppo package on OpenWrt's python

Tags: python, openwrt

cpppo working fine on windows.
Can I run cpppo package ( https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) on openwrt's python?

Comment: It says: `Linux (native or Docker containerized), Mac and Windows OSs are supported`. I'm not sure if anyone tried to run it on OpenWRT. Did you try to run it? Did you run into any errors?

Comment: Not Yet, I'm planning to get a OpenWrt  board soon and see if it runs